# How to use default value when `null` is given for a nullable function parameter?

Tags: php, null, default-value, php-7.1

In PHP 7.1 when the following function is called:

```
private function doStuff(?int $limit = 999) { }
```

with syntax like so:

```
doStuff(null);
```

the value of `$limit` becomes `null`. So I guess it can be said that the value of `$limit` was explicitly set to `null`.

Is there any way to overcome this? I.e. when a null value (i.e. the lack of a value) is encountered use the default, whether it is implicit or explicit?

Comment: I think by implicit you mean calling the function `dostuff()` without parameters, and this will take the default value, if you sent `null` value to the function, I don't think that it will take the default value all by itself, but you can still catch this inside the function and set the default value by code.

Comment: just add `if(is_null($limit)) $limit = 999;` as the first line of the function code

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish, but have you looked in to using  a ternary operator?
https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: Don't use the parameter instead by using this `dostuff();` it will use the default value you have set in the function's parameter

Comment: These are all solutions within the function, not at the parameter-definition level. Since there is now an operator ("?") AND a keyword ("= null") for this, is it possible at the parameter level?

Comment: @C0dekid this is not a solution, what about reading GET parameters which may be there and may not be there.

Comment: Passing get-parameters directly to a function may cause warning if they are not exist.

Comment: does it matter for your code that it is at param definition? if not, is it just a rethoric question?

Comment: You seem to want to have your cake yet not eat it…? You declare the parameter explicitly as *nullable*, which means you can pass `null` as its value *instead of the declared type or its default value*. And that's exactly what happens.

Comment: @deceze null is not a value, it is the lack of a value. I am explicitly saying that this is an optional parameter with a default value.

Comment: NULL __is__ a value. It's a value of special type.

Comment: `null` is of type `null` and the only valid value of that type. It *is* a value. It's just commonly used in place of "no value".

Comment: Maybe this is a language difference. In SQL null is _not_ a value, it is the lack of a value, and as such it cannot be compared (i.e. null == null does not return true). This is the clearest definition of null that I am aware of. Does PHP do things differently?

Comment: Yes, `NULL` in SQL kinda plays outside the type system. In PHP, and many other languages for that matter, it's simply yet another type/value.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No PHP doesn't have a "fallback to default if null" option. You should instead do:

```
private function dostuff(?int $limit = null) {
    // pre-int typehinting I would have done is_numeric($limit) ? $limit : 999;
    $limit = $limit ?? 999;
}
```

Alternatively make sure you either do `dostuff()` or `dostuff(999)` when you don't have a sensible value for doing stuff.

**Note**: There's also reflection to get the default values of method parameters but that seems a too much.

However here's how:

```
 $m = new ReflectionFunction('dostuff');
 $default = $m->getParameters()[0]->getDefaultValue();
 dostuff($default);
```

Comment: Simpler: `$limit ?? 999`

Comment: @NikiC True it can be simplified.

Comment: You should not use implicate nullable, it's deprecated and will be removed from PHP in future.

change `dostuff(?int $limit = null)` to `dostuff(int $limit = null)`

If you provide a default of null, you do not need to provide type nullability.

source: https://twitter.com/kocsismate90/status/1730711133042958637

Comment: @SlyDave implicable nullable is `dostuff(int $limit = null)` (and is indeed not recommended to be used). The type `?int` is explicitly nullable.

Comment: You're totally right, I was reading things backwards - and Laravel Pint has been stripping nulalble from code, which has now been fixed in https://github.com/laravel/pint/issues/235 ! 

Please disregard my previous comment !